# How to download file directly to aws storage using lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, zoom-sdk

im working on integrating zoom into my application and im stuck at a certain point.
So basically i want to get the zoom recordings of a user and download it into my aws s3 bucket.
using the zoom api to get recordings give you two links, a play link which leads you into zoom ui with the video of the recording and a download link. I want the users zoom recordings to play on my website using my ui, therefore i need to use the download link. Therefore i want to use my back end server (node) to get the download link and download the file then upload the file to aws.
Is that in anyway possible? or is there another way i could go about this problem?. Please i am in dire need of this help.
Thanks.

Comment: Is your problem getting the download link or downloading the file once you get it or uploading the file to aws?

Comment: my problem is using the download link to upload the file to aws?.....

Comment: Can't you just download the file on the server and then upload it to AWS? or maybe consider using a serverless function if you don't want to burden your  server

Comment: yeah i was thinking  of using a lambda function to do that but i justy wanted to ask and see if aws has a method built in for that

Comment: In that case I would phrase the question like this "How to download file directly to AWS storage" people rarely unswer unclear questions or questions containing multiple unclear areas